# Comparing text from speech to a child name in firebase with android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Brief description of the App:
The user click on a button that will trigger the Speech to Text API (google API). The text from speech is compared to some children in firebase. The comparsion is to the name of the child (not the value of the child). If the text from speech is like one of the children it sets the value of the this child to 1.

For example, My firebase:

```
 numbers
   three:0
   four:0
   five:0
```

If the user says three it will set the value "1" to three's value.

The problem is that the result of google speech to text Api gives more than one word(For example, if the user says three it returns: 3 tree three),  and there is no LIKE clause in firebase

So how can I compare between the text from speech to the child name in firebase?
I would add my code but I think I'm far from the right answer.
Thank you very much (I hope you understand the question).